# Server Throughput definition ambiguity

Tags: server, jmeter, newrelic, stress-testing, throughput

Is throughput the max number of requests a server instance *can* handle or is it the number of requests that the server instance is *currently* handling?

Edit: By "currently handling" I mean, the number of requests the server is receiving for a given time interval in recent time. For eg: The server is currently handling 400 reqs every min.

For eg:, I might have a server instance with a lot of hardware which *can* have high throughput, but I might be only receiving small amount of traffic. What does throughput measure in such a situation. Also, what about the inverse case, i.e if my instance can only handle x requests per min. but is receiving y>>>x requests per min.

If throughput is the max no. of requests a server can handle, how is it measured? Do we do a load/stress test, where we keep increasing the requests per min on the server until it cannot handle them anymore?

Answer (score 0):

No, [Throughput](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) is an aggregation that depends on execution time, you can send 1000 requests in the same second and your server won't handle, but when you'll send 1000 requests in an hour and your server will handle it normally.

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>   The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

You want to find the number of concurrent users that your server can handle by increasing JMeter threads until server reach his maximum

Answer (score 0):

Throughput is the number of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which JMeter executes within the duration of your test. If you want to see the actual amount of requests which are being sent - consider using i.e. [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listener (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

If you see that your server resources consumption doesn't increase as you increase the load in JMeter the reasons are in:

1. Your application middleware configuration is not suitable for high load (i.e. there is a limit of concurrent sessions and requests are queuing up instead of being processed), check out [Web Performance Optimization: Top 3 Server and Client-Side Performance Tips](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/) for overall ideas what could be looked at
2. Your application code doesn't utilize underlying OS resources efficiently, consider using [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to see what's going on under the hood.
3. JMeter may fail to send requests fast enough, make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if JMeter's machine is overloaded - consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)